# How to fix poco Poco::Net::TCPServerParams() valgrind definite leak

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, poco-libraries

I am using Poco and I am creating TCP server params as below:
Poco::Net::TCPServerParams *pParams = new Poco::Net::TCPServerParams();

When I use Valgring, I get definite memory leak:
   1271 ==00:00:01:37.131 48682==    at 0x4C2903F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
)

at line: Poco::Net::TCPServerParams *pParams = new Poco::Net::TCPServerParams();

Poco version:
dpkg -l | grep poco
ii  libpoco-dev                            1.6.1-AVA3                       amd64        C++ Portable Components (POCO) Development files
ii  libpoconet31                           1.6.1-AVA3                       amd64        C++ Portable Components (POCO) Network library

To fix it, I used delete on the pointer and but I get an error

`delete pParams`

'TCPServerParams.h:98:10: error: ‘virtual Poco::Net::TCPServerParams::~TCPServerParams()’ is protected'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to use `TCPServerParams` is that it works with `TCPServer` together. First you create `TCPServerParams` by `new` then it is passed into `TCPServer` which takes ownership of params. It is described in [reference of TCPServer](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.TCPServer.html).

> The server also takes ownership of the TCPServerParams object.

so `TCPServer` deletes param instance where it is no needed.

---

You cannot delete `TCPServerParams` manually by `delete` because destructor is protected.

In Poco library many classes have protected destructor, it forces you to use `Poco::AutoPtr` class to manage lifetime of instances.

`TCPServerParams` derives from `RefCountedObject`. `RefCountedObject` provides reference counter mechanism. It has `release` method which deletes an object when the lifetime of `AutoPtr` ends.

So you could write:

```
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::TCPServerParams> p(new Poco::Net::TCPServerParams());
```

and memory is released automatically by `AutoPtr`.